# При выполнении скрипта возникла ошибка. Включить расширенный вывод ошибок можно в файле настроек .settings.php

Tags: php, битрикс

С сайта на bitrix пропали некоторые стили. Сделал восстановление через резервную копию. БД не восстанавливал. Теперь не могу попасть ни в админку, ни на сайт пишет: "При выполнении скрипта возникла ошибка. Включить расширенный вывод ошибок можно в файле настроек .settings.php". Помогите, пожалуйста, желательно очень подробно, так как не имею опыта работы с бэком

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле /bitrix/.settings.php найдите строку `'exception_handling' =>`. Ниже находятся настройки обработки ошибок. Парой строк ниже замените `'debug' => false,` на `'debug' => true,`. После этого включится расширенный вывод ошибок, и вы увидите, где возникла проблема.